# set default values of a List in FlutterFlow Widget from FireStore Collection

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutterflow

I am trying to use the package calendar_date_picker2 (https://pub.dev/packages/calendar_date_picker2/example) in my FlutterFlow App. I have created a widget to display the calendar and it all looks good.

The widget by default loads the values defined in the
class _MyHomePageState (as show in the example code)
[default values in the list _multiDatePickerValueWithDefaultValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yaf5.png)

I want to set the default values of what the user has previous selected on their calendar (stored in FireStore database as List  "plannedDays" in "user" collection.

How can I use the data stored in FireStore collection instead of the defaultValues as stated in the example.

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

I am trying to run a query on the authenticated user collection and assign the output to a List<DateTime?> and then assign it to _multiDatePickerValueWithDefaultValue.

But since this is my first time, I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.